# Как разбить xml на колонки excel

Tags: парсер, xml, excel, csv

Есть такой xml файл, в котором есть записи.

```
<post>
<Title>What Is Bigos? (Correct answer)</Title>
<Content>
<p>What is Bigos and how is it used?</p>
<ul>
<li>
As a dish that does not spoil quickly and only gets tastier with each reheating,
<b>bigos</b>
has been traditionally used as a provision for travellers and campers or consumed at outdoor events, such as a hunt [more]
</li>
</ul>
<h2>What is bigos called in English?</h2>
Bigos (Polish pronunciation: [ˈbʲiɡɔs]; Belarusian: і, bihas, or і, bihus, Lithuanian: bigusas), often translated into English as hunter's stew, is [more]
<h2>What does bigos taste like?</h2>
In 17
<sup>th</sup>
century cuisine, bigos was either made sour with vinegar, lemons, limes, or even with sorrel or gooseberries; made sweet with [more]
<p style="text-align: center;"></p>
<h2>How do you make bigos?</h2>
Bigos Recipe Cut your washed cabbage in thin slices and boil until tender in a pot. Boil the sauerkraut in [more]
<h2>How many calories are in a bigos?</h2>
Hunter's Stew Bigos (1 cup) contains 13g total carbs, 9g net carbs, 15g fat, 2g protein, and 180 calories.
<h2>Can bigos be frozen?</h2>
"Bigos " may be frozen so we can make a substantial quantity of the dish and store it in our [more]
<h2></h2>
My dad used to make hunter's stew but he called it kapusta, which means cabbage in Polish. Hunter's stew, also [more]
<h2>What is the national dish of Brazil?</h2>
Feijoada is a black bean stew that is brewed with a variety of salted and smoked pork and beef products [more]
<h2>What is the national dish of Poland?</h2>
Bigos stew is the national dish of Poland. It can be made with any kind of meat from pork to [more]
<h2>What is the Polish word for sauerkraut?</h2>
The real confusion comes in because, while each of these preparations may have their own proper (long) name, ( kapusta [more]
```

Я бы хотел, чтобы в таблице эксель этот пост пропарсился на заголовки и контент, который находится под заголовком. Картинку приложил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У кого какие идеи?

Comment: Вы можете попробовать использовать XSLT для преобразования XML в подходящий формат для Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать XSLT для преобразования XML в подходящий формат для Excel.

Вот как это сделать.

**Входной XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<post>
    <Title>What Is Bigos? (Correct answer)</Title>
    <Content>
        <p>What is Bigos and how is it used?</p>
        <ul>
            <li>As a dish that does not spoil quickly and only gets tastier with each reheating,
                <b>bigos</b>has been traditionally used as a provision for travellers and campers or consumed at outdoor events, such as a hunt [more]</li>
        </ul>
        <h2>What is bigos called in English?</h2>Bigos (Polish pronunciation: [ˈbʲiɡɔs]; Belarusian: і, bihas, or і, bihus, Lithuanian: bigusas), often translated into English as hunter's stew, is [more]
        <h2>What does bigos taste like?</h2>In 17
        <sup>th</sup>century cuisine, bigos was either made sour with vinegar, lemons, limes, or even with sorrel or gooseberries; made sweet with [more]
        <p style="text-align: center;"></p>
        <h2>How do you make bigos?</h2>Bigos Recipe Cut your washed cabbage in thin slices and boil until tender in a pot. Boil the sauerkraut in [more]
        <h2>How many calories are in a bigos?</h2>Hunter's Stew Bigos (1 cup) contains 13g total carbs, 9g net carbs, 15g fat, 2g protein, and 180 calories.
        <h2>Can bigos be frozen?</h2>"Bigos " may be frozen so we can make a substantial quantity of the dish and store it in our [more]
        <h2></h2>My dad used to make hunter's stew but he called it kapusta, which means cabbage in Polish. Hunter's stew, also [more]
        <h2>What is the national dish of Brazil?</h2>Feijoada is a black bean stew that is brewed with a variety of salted and smoked pork and beef products [more]
        <h2>What is the national dish of Poland?</h2>Bigos stew is the national dish of Poland. It can be made with any kind of meat from pork to [more]
        <h2>What is the Polish word for sauerkraut?</h2>The real confusion comes in because, while each of these preparations may have their own proper (long) name, ( kapusta [more]</Content>
</post>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/post">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="Content/h2">
                <row>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    <content>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(./following-sibling::text()[1])"/>
                    </content>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Выходной XML**

```
<post>
  <row>
    <h2>What is bigos called in English?</h2>
    <content>Bigos (Polish pronunciation: [ˈbʲiɡɔs]; Belarusian: і, bihas, or і, bihus, Lithuanian: bigusas), often translated into English as hunter's stew, is [more]</content>
  </row>
  <row>
    <h2>What does bigos taste like?</h2>
    <content>In 17</content>
  </row>
  <row>
    <h2>How do you make bigos?</h2>
    <content>Bigos Recipe Cut your washed cabbage in thin slices and boil until tender in a pot. Boil the sauerkraut in [more]</content>
  </row>
  <row>
    <h2>How many calories are in a bigos?</h2>
    <content>Hunter's Stew Bigos (1 cup) contains 13g total carbs, 9g net carbs, 15g fat, 2g protein, and 180 calories.</content>
  </row>
  <row>
    <h2>Can bigos be frozen?</h2>
    <content>"Bigos " may be frozen so we can make a substantial quantity of the dish and store it in our [more]</content>
  </row>
  <row>
    <h2/>
    <content>My dad used to make hunter's stew but he called it kapusta, which means cabbage in Polish. Hunter's stew, also [more]</content>
  </row>
  <row>
    <h2>What is the national dish of Brazil?</h2>
    <content>Feijoada is a black bean stew that is brewed with a variety of salted and smoked pork and beef products [more]</content>
  </row>
  <row>
    <h2>What is the national dish of Poland?</h2>
    <content>Bigos stew is the national dish of Poland. It can be made with any kind of meat from pork to [more]</content>
  </row>
  <row>
    <h2>What is the Polish word for sauerkraut?</h2>
    <content>The real confusion comes in because, while each of these preparations may have their own proper (long) name, ( kapusta [more]</content>
  </row>
</post>
```

Comment: А как открыть выходной XML?

Я чуть изучил XSLT, я в XML подключил <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="import.xsl"?>  вверху.
Но как открыть выходной XML?

Или я сделал что-то не так?

Comment: How to Import XML to Excel: https://www.guru99.com/connecting-microsoft-excel-to-external-data-sources.html